# Why my useState doesn't work as it should?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a sidebar in my react app, and when the screen is mobile, it goes to the top and only the button "menu" remains, and when clicked it should display the sidebar.
Example is below:
Sidebar:
[image]

Sidebar with mobile screen(with clicked button):

[image]

So I have a code like this:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    const [sideBar, setSidebar] = useState(false);


    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <span class="btn">Menu</span>
            <div className="profile">
                <span>Alim Budaev</span>
                <span>Available for work</span>
            </div>
            <ul className="sidebarlist" id={setSidebar ? "hidden" : ""}>
            {SlidebarData.map((val,key) =>{
                return (
                <li 
                    className="row"
                    id={window.location.pathname == val.link ? "active" : ""}
                    key={key} 
                    onClick={()=> {
                        window.location.pathname = val.link
                    }}>
                    {""}
                    <div>
                        {val.title}
                    </div>
                    </li>
                );
            })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

So as you could see, I'm using useState(), so when state is true, the "hidden" id should be added to ul and it should display, but state is false in my code, and it display anyway:

[image]

I'm not sure what could be the problem, but I think if state is false, the "hidden" id shouldn't be added, and the sidebar shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: This is a general thing, but it's very odd to use `id` for a `"hidden"` tag. That's the sort of thing that's likely to appear in multiple places and is much more suited to a class. (Same thing with `"active"`)

Comment: Also, you are using `setSidebar` not `sideBar` in your conditional here `setSidebar ? "hidden" : ""`

Comment: @DBS, yeaah, using "sideBar" helped, but hidden is id because it has another styles, which apply to a whole a sidebar